# Calling imagemagick convert out of python script fails

Tags: python, imagemagick

I want to use imagemagick to remove backgrounds from product images. The command is `convert "C:\Users\andi\Desktop\T-Shirts\input.jpg" -alpha set -channel RGBA -fuzz 20% -fill none -floodfill +0+0 white "C:\Users\andi\Desktop\T-Shirts\input.jpg-freeTee.png"`, which works fine, if called from a dos box.

When it is called out of a python script, I get following error message:

```
is file: C:\Users\andi\Desktop\T-Shirts\input.jpg
call: convert "C:\Users\andi\Desktop\T-Shirts\input.jpg" -alpha set -channel RGBA -fuzz 20% -fill none -floodfill +0+0 white "C:\Users\andi\Desktop\T-Shirts\input.jpg-freeTee.png"
convert.exe: unable to open image `"C:\Users\andi\Desktop\T-Shirts\input.jpg"': Invalid argument @ error/blob.c/OpenBlob/2705.
convert.exe: unable to open module file `C:\Program Files\ImageMagick-6.9.5-Q16\modules\coders\IM_MOD_RL_JPG"_.dll': No such file or directory @ warning/module.c/GetMagickModulePath/676.
convert.exe: no decode delegate for this image format `JPG"' @ error/constitute.c/ReadImage/504.
convert.exe: no images defined `"C:\Users\andi\Desktop\T-Shirts\input.jpg-freeTee.png"' @ error/convert.c/ConvertImageCommand/3257.

C:\Users\andi\Desktop\T-Shirts>
```

Of course I checked for the file `C:\Program Files\ImageMagick-6.9.5-Q16\modules\coders\IM_MOD_RL_JPG"_.dll`, which exists.

I tried it with imagemagick 6.9.5 and 7.0.3. In the version 7, I tried it with the legacy `convert` and the new `magick` command.

The python code used to call imagemagick is:

```
def freeTheTee(file):
    inkscape_dir=r"C:\Program Files\ImageMagick-6.9.5-Q16"
    assert os.path.isdir(inkscape_dir)
    os.chdir(inkscape_dir)
    from subprocess import call
    print "call: " + " ".join(["convert", "\"" + file + "\"", "-alpha", "set", "-channel", "RGBA", "-fuzz", "20%", "-fill", "none", "-floodfill", "+0+0", "white", "\"" + file + "-freeTee.png\""])
    call(["convert", "\"" + file + "\"", "-alpha", "set", "-channel", "RGBA", "-fuzz", "20%", "-fill", "none", "-floodfill", "+0+0", "white", "\"" + file + "-freeTee.png\""])
```

To call the python script, I use a short batch file, where I drop my files on to be converted:

```
start cmd /k call c:\Python27\python.exe "%~dp0\FreeTheTee.py" %*
```

This opens a new dos box, where the python script runs and fails. When I now copy out the output of the script (which is the first command in this posting) , paste it in the same dos box and execute it, then imagemagick is doing the conversion successfully. This happens in Windows. I first developed the script on a Mac, where it just works like a charm.

Any ideas?

edit: used simpler file names to be sure it's not "spaces in filename related"

Comment: Windows is notoriously awful at dealing with spaces, single quotes, percent signs, parentheses and and anything tougher than `echo hello`, so try simplifying things down by putting all files in the working directory and removing anything too tough till it runs, then slowly add stuff back in till it does what you want.

Comment: I agree, maybe start by renaming the file to remove the ``` (1)``` at the end or escaping the spaces and brackets with slashes. You can see how windows is viewing the paths if you try an ```os.listdir('.')``` in the directory with the files?

Comment: I share your view about windows filename handling... i renamed the input file to `input.jpg` and got the same problem. I edited the original question to reflect the changes and the different output.

Comment: Use python subprocess to call an imagemagick command or a bash shell script.